# Size of files was increased after splitting by Ffmpeg

Tags: batch-file, video, split, ffmpeg, size

I use this code to split file to multiple parts:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.mp4) do ( 
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:05 "D:\Ebook\%%~ni_1.mp4"
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 "D:\Ebook\%%~ni_2.mp4"
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:10 "D:\Ebook\%%~ni_3.mp4"
  )
pause
```

It worked but I have a problem. It is total size of parts is larger than original file.

Original: 700 MB and after splitting:

```
Part 1: 225
Part 1: 500
Part 2: 250
```

Why ? And how to keep same quality and size of files after splitting ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Probably the splitter sets meta information and for almost sure additional BOMs.you can try binary split instead but the parts wont be playable

Comment: Hi, there is no solution for it ?

Comment: There is - binary split. But the parts will be not movies

Comment: ffmpeg is supposed to directly copy the data without re-encoding, using copy, right?  It shouldn't grow by 250 MB or more, but my experience is with avi splitting in the old days.  Try a different splitter perhaps, and make sure you `add up the run time` of all three pieces to ensure than they are the same as the single piece.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your first chunk is seconds (0,5), your second chunk is seconds (5,15) and your third chunk is (10, end) [note the overlap between second and third chunk]

the "-t" is "how much time to keep going" ref: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options